# Can I profile a running method through v8-profiler

Tags: node.js, v8-profiler

I'm using `v8-profiler` to investigate a CPU 100% issue on my production site. In order to figure out which API causes my CPU issue I started the profiler when the application detect CPU > 90%. But unfortunately when I opened the profile file I cannot find any functions which takes more than 100ms.

I would like to check if the CPU-sensitive function was invoked then the profiler began to work, will it be captured or not. I checked the README of `v8-profiler` but they didn't mentioned and all samples I can find are all follow the procedure that's start-profile -> begin CPU-sensitive function function -> save-profile.